# What is the Topology of a Twice-Punctured Hypersphere (n>2)?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, spheres

From a topological standpoint, what topological space is produced by deleting two points from an $n$-sphere $\mathbb{S}^n$ for $n \geq 3$?

- For a 1-sphere $\mathbb{S}^1$ (i.e., a circle), deleting two points produces two lines.
- For a 2-sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ (a sphere), deleting two points produces a cylinder.

For both cases, $n=1$ and $n=2$, deleting two points produces a shape topologically equivalent to an $(n-1)$-sphere extruded along a perpendicular direction (e.g., twice-punctured $\mathbb{S}^2$ is equivalent to a cylinder which can be constructed from a circle in the x-y plane extruded along the z-axis).

Does this pattern extend to higher dimensions?

Comment: Up to homeomorphism you can suppose the two points are the north and south poles of the sphere, and then do a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_cylindrical_projection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [$\mathbb{S}^n$ punctured once is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675031), $\mathbb{S}^n$ punctured twice is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}.$

Comment: Thanks. How do we know that $\mathbb{S}^n$ punctured once is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @PaulWintz Stereographic projection.

Comment: Ah, right! Thanks!